# rails ActiveRecord::Observer in plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to add an Observer for Issues to an existing rails application.

I created a plugin, and under plugin's `app/model` i saved the `custom_observer.rb`

It works when I add `:custom_observer` to `config.active_record.observers` in `config/application.rb`

I tried something like

```
RedmineApp::Application.configure do
    config.after_initialize do
             config.active_record.observers << :custom_observer
    end
end
```

in the plugin's init.rb but that doesn't work.

What is a better way to do that?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Rails 4.0, [observers have been extracted](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ccecab3ba950a288b61a516bf9b6962e384aae0b) out of the core into a gem called [`rails-observers`](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers)

Although you've not said which version of rails you're using, if you're using rails 4, I'd recommend doing this:

**GemFile**

```
#Rails Observers
gem "rails-observers", "~> 0.1.2"
```

**Config**

```
#config/application.rb
#Observer Classes
config.active_record.observers = :custom_observer
```

**Observer**

```
#models/customer_observer.rb
class CustomObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
end
```

Works for us, and I've supplied live code for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue addressed in this blogpost: [ActiveRecord observers in gems/plugins](https://web.archive.org/web/20100307150643/http://riotprojects.com/post/106808946/activerecord-observers-in-gems-plugins)